# Is it possible to get the name of the type being passed in the calling function/method?

Tags: c#

If I have a method that takes an enum parameter and I call it from a razor view (for example) with this..

```
var test = TestViewModel.InitiateRadioButtons(Model.Project.General.Information.StartedBy)
```

where StartedBy is an enum called StartedByGroups

then, in the method being called it takes a type of this enum e.g.

```
public static List<RadioButtonVM> InitiateRadioButtons(GeneralInfo.StartedByGroups selected)
```

How can I get the name of the type being passed into that method e.g. `Model.Project.General.Information.StartedBy`

Many thanks

Comment: Does `selected.GetType().Name` is what you need? Or you need enum value name? Then you can take `Enum.GetName` method: `string s = Enum.GetName(typeof(GeneralInfo.StartedByGroups), selected);`

Comment: is it an object type or enum? For type `selected.GetType().Name`, for enum `selected.ToString()`

Comment: None of these seem to work. The problem is I'm passing the enum that's part of a more complex object. I want to get that complex object name. But I don't think it's possible as the method being called is only concerned about the enum type, not where it has come from?

Comment: I suppose forget it's an enum, if I had `public string myMethod(string myString)` and I passed it an object that was a string within a complex object e.g. `var s = myMethod(Team.Person.Address.AddressLine1)` then how in the method being called would I get `Team.Person.Address.AddressLine1`? Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: No, that is not possible. It is somewhat possible if you pass an `Expression<Func<string>>` instead (`() => Team.Person.Address.AddressLine1`), as you can then analyze that expression tree before compiling it and getting the value, but that's quite involved. I would just settle for passing the name explicitly, or, if it's for troubleshooting purposes, to do things with [caller information](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/caller-information).

Comment: The fact that you even want this data makes me think you are doing something wrong and whatever you want to do can be done in another, better, way. For this reason it's usually good to include _what_ you are trying to achieve in your question, not just _how_.